# Android apk with Firebase Test LAB

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-test-lab

So I implement Admob ads to my apk and I want to upload my apk to Firebase Test Lab to make some test. But I'm not sure if it's okay to upload apk with ads to there. So my question is: Can I upload my apk with live ads to firebase to make some tests?

Comment: No, Users have to click on live ads when app is in live only. while testing users may be click on adds in that time google will identify same person is clicking with same device id. so google will restrict/stop adds few months.

Comment: So can i get banned for showing live ads in firebase test lab?

Comment: Actually not for showing ads its for click on ads they will banned.

Answer (score 3):

I used firebase test lab pre-launch report with live ads for a year with no issue, but my last app got suspended for clicks on test lab.  I was having issues with screen loading on an version of Android and I think the lab may have clicked the ads in those tests, but doesn't normally click ads.  You could probably verify after each pre-launch report on the adsense console that you're not getting clicks and be fine, if you see clicks disable immediately.  Test lab does provide an IP address range, but it is not clear on how to programmaticly exclude these IP addresses, e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/overview#testlab_and_mobile_advertising